# JavaScript. Understanding e/Events

Tags: javascript, function, events

I've purchased a book on JavaScript. I've understood everything up until editing code to work with anything < IE9

There is a simple example which checks a username input to be more than 5 characters.
That's easy.
then they introduced events into the functions.

in the code below, I've included comments on the parts I need assistance with..

```
function checkLength(e, minLength) {  //I understand parameters, but what is 'e' plugging?
    var el, elMsg;  

  if (!e) {  //So... if event doesn't exist.(IE8) then use window.event?
    e = window.event;
  }
  el = e.target || e.srcElement;  //What exactly is the event targeting?
  elMsg = el.nextSibling;

  if (el.value.length < minLength) {
    elMsg.innerHTML = 'Username must be ' + minLength + ' characters or more';
  } else {
    elMsg.innerHTML = '';
  }
}

var elUsername = document.getElementById('username');

if (elUsername.addEventListener) {
    elUsername.addEventListener('blur', function(e) { //what am i passing?
    checkLength(e, 5);
  }, false);
} else {
    elUsername.attachEvent('onBlur', function(e) {
    checkLength(e, 5);
  });
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

Comment: *"what am i passing?"* The string `'blur'` and a function (and `false`).

Answer (score 1):

> I understand parameters, but what is 'e' plugging?

`e` comes from the event handler and represents the event itself.

> So... if event doesn't exist.(IE8) then use window.event?

Some versions of IE use a [global event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) that is only available while an event is being handled. If the event is not passed into the function, use IE's global event instead.

> What exactly is the event targeting?

The event `target` or `srcElement` is the element being acted upon. If you have a click handler on a button this will refer to the button, if you have a change or blur handler on an input, it will reference the input element, etc.

> what am i passing?

the first parameter is the name of the event you want to handle and the second parameter is the function that will handle the event.